# PHP Erroe: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl'

Tags: php

Trying to enable intl php extension, I keep getting same error, can't figure out why.

Here are the steps I followed:

MacOS

Php 7.3
(I don`t have XAMMP)

What I've done:

Uncheck extension=intl

Tried with intl.dll and intl.so -- same error

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Look in the folder `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731` and see what files are available

Comment: xdebug.so and opcache.so

Comment: So from your zip/tar file that you downloaded 7.3 you should be able to copy that intl extension into that directory. You can also instead run something like `php -i | grep ini` which will tell you potential other `.ini` files that are being parsed that might be loading that extension beyond what you expect.